# Physical Key State

Tags: windows, winapi, input, keyboard, keyboard-events

The two key-state functions in the WIndows API, `GetKeyState()` and `GetAsyncKeyState()`, both determine key state based on key up/down messages rather than the physical state of the key.

I am working on a program which manipulates input, using `SendInput()`,  to release modifier keys (alt, ctrl, etc...), send input, and then re-press the modifier keys.

The problem is that I don't know if the modifier keys are still pressed after the input is sent because I have sent the key-up event and both of the above mentioned functions return that the key is up regardless of the state of the physical key. So if I assume they are still down, the user is left with a dangling ctrl-down causing problems until the user presses and releases cntl again (or any modifier key). Otherwise the key may be left up even when the physical key is still down.

So is there any way (preferably without anything too low level) to detect the physical key state. Windows-only methods are fine. Key monitoring (listening for key up events) really isn't possible (or at least really, really not preferable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing, I seem to have figured it out. MSDN states about `GetKeyState()` :

> The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue.

`GetAsyncKeyState()` still works on key up/down messages (not physical key state) however, it just doesn't wait for the message to be read. So if a key event message is sent via `SendInput()`, it will still return incorrectly - in fact, it will be incorrect before `GetKeyState()` because it will be incorrect immediately after the call.

A simple test to demonstrate this functionality is [here](https://bitbucket.org/cschouggins/keystate/downloads/KeyState.rar) (VS2010 solution) or just the source [here](https://bitbucket.org/cschouggins/keystate/src/d5b8d781d104/KeyState.cpp).

Comment: "GetAsyncKeyState() still works on key up/down messages (not physical key state)" is simply at odds with [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That's irrelevant. This is how it works. As soon as a key event is posted, the return value of GetAsyncKeyState() changes.

Comment: They key goes down, the message is posted. Yes, that's pretty much what happens!

Comment: Or if a key event is simulated via SendInput() - the whole point of this question.

Comment: Whatever. It's all explained in MSDN. You believe MSDN is wrong.

Comment: MSDN does not explicitly describe the implementation. Aside from SendInput(), it does work as MSDN states. But you clearly don't care and have come across the problem, if you ever find a need to simulate user input and detect key states, remember this post.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't giving the window manager enough time to process the input you just injected. Until it reaches the "update key states for `GetAsyncKeyState`" part of the code, `GetAsyncKeyState` will report the old value. (In particular, it won't reach that point until all low-level keyboard hooks have had a chance to inspect the action and possibly reject it.)

In other words, your code has a race condition, and that is what you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a bit confused here. In fact `GetAsyncKeyState()` does return the key state at the instant that `GetAsyncKeyState()` was called. On the other hand, `GetKeyState()` returns the key state based on the history of queued messages.

Comment: MSDN claims this same thing, however in testing, it does not hold. After a key up event is sent, GetAsyncKeyState() does in fact report that the key is up, regardless of the physical key state. (Win7 64-bit)

Comment: So you think something as fundamental as this is broken in Windows and nobody has noticed for 25 years?

Comment: I know that it will return the incorrect result after sending a key up event.

Comment: It looks like you have found a bug in that case. Please submit a bug report to MS. Remember to include a full working code sample that demonstrates the problem you have discovered.

Comment: @ChadSchouggins; when using GetAsyncKeyState, be sure to check only the high bit of the SHORT to check the key state. A very common mistake is to check the low bit or just check that the overall value is non-zero, which will give you an incorrect result. See MSDN for full details. This is different than GetKeyState() where you can usually get away with just comparing against zero; you can't just replace one with the other.

Comment: @BrendanMcK Thanks, but I am only checking the high bit.