# VBA GetAsyncKeystate

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to capture keys strokes using the GetAsyncKeystate.

I am aware this can be done using `Application.Onkey` but I want to ensure that the code is not fired multiple times when the key is held down and I know this can be done using GetAsyncKeystate storing the previous state in variable for later comparison.

I currently have the following declared in a public module:

```
#If Win64 Then
  Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeystate Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

#Else
  Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeystate Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

#End If
```

Then in the module which contains my main code I am trying to do something along the lines of:

```
Sub KeyPressed
  'If KeyPressed is X key then
      'Do something

  'Or if KeyPressed is Y key then
      'Do something else

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *I know this can be done [...] storing the previous state in variable for later comparison* - so, have you tried storing the previous state in a variable for later comparison?

Comment: IIR, `GetAsyncKeystate` isn't always reliable from inside the context of Office applications - they mess with the keystate. On top of that, I'd give [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8275874/4088852) a read - I doubt this is the appropriate API for what you're trying to do. AFAIK there isn't a reliable way to do what you're looking for without sinking a subclass into the message pump.

Comment: Mathieu, thank you. Hadn't thought to combine use of both Application.OnKey and GetAsyncKeystate!